# What is the simplest possible way for a person with a small store to sell custom products online with a paypal button and a text field?

Tags: small-business

I need a text field and a linked paypal button to put beside of each product.

Suggestions to pay a service like ebay 10% to use their paypal button are not helpful.

Something for a guy selling 5 kinds of buckets with names on it. There are complicated templates online, but editing flash templates and interconnected analytics is not needed. Just a way to add prices to buckets and check them out.

I've been at it 10 hours looking for a simple HTLM template or WordPress. (WordPress is not a solution because templates are made to have parts not editable and they interfere with the plugin. Unless you know an exact combination of "template" and plugin that works.

Comment: You might want to try asking on StackOverflow if no one has a suggestion here.

Comment: Have you tried the Paypal *button factory*. You need a Paypal business account to use it, something that you will want anyway.

Comment: @Rich This will *definitely* not be on-topic for Stack Overflow, which deals in specific programming questions, not recommendations for general architectural design.

Comment: Barry, users of this site are not necessarily able to give programming or HTML advice. However, chepner is right that this question would be off-topic on [SO], as written. One way to start is by searching for [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpaypal%5D+shopping+cart) there.

Comment: @Rich, BTW, try using `[so]` in a comment next time.

Answer (score 1):

In your PayPal account you can customize the button you need. They will generate a code and you only have to paste it on your site without using any plugins or Wordpress